# Strange rsync behavior when enabling --link-dest

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently using `rsync` with the `--link-dest` option to backup some files from Win10 (WSL) to a Debian box.

I'm observing strange behavior whereby hard linking works correctly with some folders and is completely ignored with others.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set date
date='date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M"'

# Source
source=/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/test/

# Partial destination
dest=/media/external/user/laptop/desktop/

# log into server and retrieve last updated folder
last=`ssh -p XXXX -i ~/key user@hostname.org 'cd '$dest'; ls -ct | head -n 1'`

# --link-dest from the last updated folder
link_dest=/media/external/user/laptop/desktop/$last

rsync -PaSh --mkpath --delete --link-dest=$link_dest --stats -e 'ssh -p XXXX -i ~/key' $source user@hostname.org:$dest`$date/`
```

The `--link-dest` is inconsistent.
A small test folder with three png image files works correctly.

On the first run all files are fully transferred.

Subsequent runs correctly pick up the `--link-dest` and only transfer changes, if there are any:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
304K    ./10-10-2021-12:46
4.0K    ./10-10-2021-12:51
4.0K    ./10-10-2021-12:47
4.0K    ./10-10-2021-12:49
320K    .
```

I also get the same results with a small folder with some Word files.

However, with other folders e.g. larger folders jpg images files etc, the subsequent runs do not copy only the changed files, but instead overwrite the original folder.

For example, the original run:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
756M    ./10-10-2021-22:04
756M    .
```

Second run:

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1
756M    ./10-10-2021-22:07
756M    .
```

The **only** change I made to the script is the source folder: `source=/mnt/c/Users/user/Desktop/XXX/`. No other changes.

I cannot explain why `--link-dest` works in some cases and fails in others and whether that's somehow related to the type of files or the size of the folder.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: The line `'cd '$dest'; ls -ct | head -n 1'` is erroneous and only works by chance. Change it to `"cd '$dest'; ls -ct | head -n 1"`. Better still, change it to `"cd '$dest' && ls -ct | head -n 1"`. These days you shouldn't be writing new code with backticks; use `$( ... )` instead. Double-quote your variables when you use them (e.g. `"$link_dest"` and `"$source"` on the `rsync` line itself)

Comment: 1. Duplicate the `rsync` line, and then prefix the first one with `echo` so you can see what it's planning to do. Does it match your expectation? 2. Add the `-iv` flags (`--itemize-changes --verbose`). What does it report for the files that are being unexpectedly overwritten? Please add examples of this to your question

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion worked. Do you want to repeat it as an answer, so I can award it to you?